# injecting codes (methods) into class?

Tags: php, oop

Take this simple code:

```
class MyClass {
   public $customFunction = array();

   public function run($name){
       call_user_func($this->customFunction[$name]);
   }
}

//> Usage:

$c = new MyClass();
$c->customFunction['first'] = function (){ /* some code*/ };

$c->run('first');
```

This cose works as excpted. I add that function to `$customFunction` and then i can call it form `run();` method.

The problem comes when in my injected function I try to do something object-related, for example if i add this function:

```
$c->customFunction['first'] = function(){ $this->callsomemethod(); }
```

When i call the `run();` method PHP says I can't use `$this` in a static context.

Do I have some way to inject those function and be able to use the object method?

(Note: of course my class is just an example, I need this for a scope)
Thanks

### Thanks to Mario, here the solution I will use:

```
public function run($name) {
    call_user_func($this->customFunction[$name],$this);
}
```

At this point i just need to add function with a parm like this:

```
= function ($this) { /*some code*/};
```

And `$this` will emulate the object-context scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error originates in the code you have shown as `/* some code*/` in your example.

You assign an anonymous function here:

```
$c->customFunction['first'] = function (){ /* some code*/ };
```

And it remains just a function. It doesn't become a real method of the class. So using `$this` within it won't work.

---

Workaround: Pass your custom functions an `$obj` parameter, and have them use that instead of `$this`. (Really, just a quirky workaround; but doable.)

```
call_user_func($this->customFunction[$name], $obj=$this);
```

Or try [`classkit_method_add`](http://php.net/classkit_method_add) or [`runkit`](http://php.net/runkit) for a "proper" solution. - If available in your PHP.

Comment: Can you pass $this as a reference?

Comment: @yes123: But take care with that. The functions can only access public properties and methods with that approach. So you would need setter or getter functions if you use too many private/protected modifiers.

Comment: @Gary: Yes, it's just an ordinary object variable/reference in read context.

Comment: So if you wanted to alter $obj it would only alter the parameter, and not the object itself UNLESS you passed by reference?

Comment: @Gary: Since PHP5 all objects are references. So you don't need to use `&` anymore. `$obj` will just become an alias to the same object behind `$this`.

Comment: @yes123: (Just seen.) You cannot use `$this` as parameter for the function. You must give that variable a distinct name. Use `$obj` or `$self` instead.

Comment: Just for quirkyness: Overridding `$this` was possible in PHP3. (But I'm not sure if downgrading is good advise just for that.)

Answer (score 2):

There's no way you can do that, sorry.

However, as usual, I do have a couple of tricks up my sleeve. :)

You can do this:

```
class Test {

    static protected $funcs_static=array();
    protected $funcs_dynamic=array();

    public static function register_static($function){
        self::$funcs_static[]=$function;
    }

    public static function register_dynamic($function){
        $this->$funcs_dynamic[]=$function;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array($name,$arguments);
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array($name,$arguments);
    }

}
```

Example of use:

```
class MyClass extends Test { }

MyClass::register_static(function(){
    echo 'bark';
});

$catdog = new MyClass();
$catdog->register_dynamic(function(){
    echo 'beow';
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure how, but it should be somehow possible to set the value of `$this` before calling a function in `__call()`. Any ideas @mario?

Comment: totally meant to flag not upvote that first comment -_-. Either way, +1 for `__call` usage.

Comment: Nah you can't access $this. I've never looked up the interna closely, but the Zend core guards that as super special variable name. You cannot even use that name for closures. :(

Comment: Ah, you can't set it even when not in use? Hmm. Ah well :(

Answer (score 1):

Use objects rather anonymous functions and follow this basic code:

```
interface Command {
    public function execute();
}

interface MyClassAware {
    public function setMyClass(MyClass $myClass);
}

class MyClass {
    private $customCommands = array();

    public function addCustomCommand($name, Command $command) {
        $this->customCommands[$name] = $command;
    }

    public function execute($name) {
        $command = $this->customCommands[$name];

        if ($command instanceof MyClassAware) {
            $command->setMyClass($this);
        } 

        $command->execute();
    }
}
```

Final usage:

```
class DoSthCommand implements Command, MyClassAware {
    private $myClass;

    public function setMyClass(MyClass $myClass) {
        $this->myClass = $myClass;
    }

    public function execute() {
        // do sth

        $this->myClass->doSthElse();

        // do sth
    }
}

$myCustomCommand = new DoSthCommand();
$myClass->addCustomCommand('doSth', $myCustomCommand);

$myClass->execute('doSth');
```

The above code relies on [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) and [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Comment: A nice addition to this would be the use of `__call` instead of needing to call `execute("name")`. +1 for the references though :D

Comment: Use of `__call` instead of `execute` would make the code much more magical, harder to document and maintain (no IDE support etc.). That would be a nice example of overuse of magic methods in PHP, cause at an end of a day it would give you nothing but all the downsides I've just mentioned.

Comment: Crozin, how is `__call` any more magical than `execute`? They are performing the same action. Neither will give you documentation on the created "command". Also, how is that overuse of magics in PHP? This is what `__call` was designed for?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [you can't do that](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures/removal-of-this).

The best you can do (at least without doing brain damage), is use __call magic and pass $this into your lambda's scope as $something_other_than_$this:

```
<?php

class Greeter {

  public $greeting = 'Hi';
  public $customFns;
  public function __construct($sayHiMethod){
    $this->customFns['sayHi'] = $sayHiMethod;
  }

  public function __call($name,$args){
    $args['caller']=$this;
    return call_user_func_array($this->customFns[$name],$args);
  }
}

$myGreeter = new Greeter(function($who,$caller){ echo "{$caller->greeting}, {$who}!\n"; });

$myGreeter->sayHi('Sally');
```

Outputs:

> Hi, Sally!

Comment: this answer looks like a mario's dup