# Store but not EXECUTE a Global Function (PHP)

Tags: php, function, oop, dependency-injection

This is an odd situation and I think the answer is 'you can't do that, what are you thinking?' but hope someone can prove me wrong.

My goal is to store a globally scoped function in a variable then inject it for execution within a class object.

- **I would like to avoid using call_user_func()** as this searches for the function in the global namespace and is the same effect as if I were to just execute the global function from within the class object. I would like my class to execute the object as if it were an internal class method, not an external function. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723045/injecting-codes-methods-into-class) comes close but not quite.
- I cannot modify the function or wrap it in a class.
- *(Why am I jumping through these hoops?)* Needs to be used within this class to follow a spec.

I know I can just duplicate the function in the class and be done with it, but you know the issues with that (plus it creeps up on SRP.) Reflection would work perfectly but this function is not in a class, it is just out there in an include. I've tried wrapping it an anonymous function and the closure object doesn't execute the function.

Is there any hope to do this? The function is simple, accepts a scalar param, does some stuff to it, returns a value (and is tightly coupled with other code, cannot be moved or changed.)

```
function someFunction($param)
{
  // do some stuff
  return $someScalarValue;
}
```

What I would hope is something like

```
$func = someFunction([some value]); // doesn't work of course, this would store result in $func
$cls = new SomeClass($func);
```

Then a method in the class could run the function object, much like call_user_func but not have to search the global namespace.

```
protected function someThing()
{
  $this->injected_function([some class value]); // also doesn't work of course
}
```

Comment: Your approach is on the right way. You can in fact pass functions stored in a variable. See my answer.

Comment: It's not clear why the linked answer does not work for you. `call_user_func` accepts a `callable`, so it does not need to "search the global space".

Comment: Sorry. I wrote the answer from scratch without testing. I've fixed my code. Hope, this helps you now.

Comment: @yivi thank you, but the function itself is in global namespace - does it not actually call someFunction() ? I searched everywhere for how call_user_func() is executed and it is not clear if it actually is running from the global namespace or within the class itself. 

Thank you both for your replies, tinkering with this now. Thank others as well for the downvotes. :-\

Comment: How about passing a method directly? I think I don't understand your problem in detail. Answer updated for another suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Markkus Zeller for your comments, as I suspected there is no way to do what I originally was tasked, to "inject" a global function as an dependency. There is, but it only really works with anonymous functions.

After a lot of stressful pushback, I convinced our managers that wrapping this in a simple class was the way to go. This,

`// require_once('some-function.php');`

```
function someFunction($param)
{
  // do some stuff
  return $someScalarValue;
}
```

. . . now becomes this. (Typed out on the fly and may contain deficiencies, concept only)

`// require_once('some-function.php');`

```
require_once('path/to/SomeFunctionClass.php');
function someFunction($param)
{
  $cls = new SomeFunctionClass($param);
  return $cls->execute();
}
```

. . . where execute() contains identical code that was in someFunction(). I can now use "SomeFunctionClass" for a DI. There is more to the story, but that is the gist, and this one change can be implemented without modifying any of the 450 or so instances that use this global function (and each of those they can be gradually ported to use the new wrapper.) It also allows me to isolate and mock the functionality for unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$this` you are in the objects instance scope. You could pass a (reference) method into the constructor.

```
$myFunc = function($arg) { var_dump($arg); return 314; };

class myClass {

  private $func;

  public function __construct($func) {
    $this->func = $func;
  }

  public function do($value) {
      $this->func->call($this, $value);
  }

}

$var = 'Hello world!';

$myObj = new myClass($myFunc);
$value = $myObj->do($var); // $value is now 314
```

If you do not want the function to be stored in global namespace you can just pass even an anonymous function like this on the fly:

```
$myObj = new myClass(function($arg) { var_dump($arg); return 314; });
$value = $myObj->do($var); // $value is now 314
```

Comment: Ok, I wrote it from Scratch. I'll test ist.

Comment: @yivi Fixed. Sorry for not testing before.

Comment: Thank you, but this stores an anonymous function as I mentioned in my original post - this is an existing function. When I do $myFunc = someFunction($arg); it executes immediately before injection. That is actually the problem. :-) Going to tinker more with it though, this has to have a solution somewhere.

Comment: Thank you again, consolidating comments here: "How about passing a method directly?" Limited space in comments. I see you've moved the anonymous function into the constructor call, same as $myVar . . . 

Imagine a legacy system we are attempting to slowly modernize. The is an include file with "someFunction()" as above in a global space. In our newly created class object, we need to access this function but it breaks unit testing because this external function makes a DB call. We need this function inside the class so we can mock it. Making any more sense?

Comment: What you need is some kind of "Registry" or "Dependency Injection".

Comment: Thank you, the class in question relies entirely on DI. That is not the problem. The real problem I suppose is that this function we need to use is an "immovable (non) object." It is referenced from 450 locations as a raw function. I cannot alter or change it, but need to use it from within this class.

If I could make it an object, wrap it with another object, I could inject it and I could go home eventually. :-D

Comment: Why not making a Singleton pattern class including this function? This class could be injected.

Comment: Do you mean basically duplicate the code in some-file.php->someFunction() in its own class as a method? I really think it's going to have to come to that, as mentioned I was hoping to avoid it but am not seeing any other way to get this function into the class.

Comment: If you need the same code in multiple classes, then consider creating an abstract class and extend that in your classes needing that method.